# How do i achieve this hooking effect with offset

Tags: hook-modifier

i need help to achieve this effect. im currently using hooks. it works fine if the hooks are on opposite ends of the object, i can move them however i like as in first picture but i need the hook to have a certain Z-offset as shown in the 2nd image and still be able to perform the same function and be in line with the object, how do i achieve that?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**: i was able to achieve this effect but i have this copy location problem, if i manually drag the empties into position (red curve arrows) it works, but it doesn't work if i use Copy Location constraint, why is that? file at https://pasteall.org/blend/b8bd4aa0de32478cb3daeeeb33a2d275

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a GN group which will let you select two objects to control the ends of your modified line, and set the offset:

[image]

(The offset can be negative, in which case the line will stretch beyond the controllers)

[image]

[image]